Gitignore all folders beginning with a period except those with a `.gitignore` file
Many tools that I use create hidden folders such as .mypy_cache, .ruff_cache, .ipynb_checkpoints, etc.
Generally, I want to git-ignore such folders, as they often only contain cached data.
However, if the folder itself contains a .gitignore file, I trust the creators of the tool to have used some sensible default. For instance, .mypy_cache creates a .gitignore with * to ignore itself, and pycharm creates a .idea folder that only ignores some files.
So, how can I recursively ignore all folders starting with a dot, except those folders that ship their own .gitignore?

This question is similar to: Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@metatoaster It's pretty clear how this question is different. They are asking how to only include certain files, I am asking to exclude all hidden folders except those that contain a .gitignore file. Those are obviously two different questions.

The point is you can ignore all folders starting with a . using .* and then add the !.gitignore as documented in one of the answer to omit the ignore. This thread would have been a better duplicate.

Just to be a little contrarian but are you really stepping on nested .gitignores ... this could only be a problem if you were ignoring something at a "higher" level and it was not supposed be ignored at a "lower" (more nested) level ... but its hard to imagine a type of file that you would really worry about that would be a problem here.

.gitignore can ignore files and directories by patterns in their names, that's all. .gitignore cannot ignore files by content or directories by files in them. That could be done manually.
You can list dot-directories with .gitignore files in them using Unix find:
find . -name .\* -type d -exec test -f "{}"/.gitignore \; -print

and add found directories to .gitignore. But you should regularly re-run the command and update your list of directories.
